# Grep last occurence from a specific file in numbered directories

Tags: file, grep, numbers

I want to grep the last line of an argument from a large number of directories which all have the same name except for a number at the end (more specifically, 0p90 -> 1p10). I want to grep the last occurrence of an argument I specified and finally, output all this to a file.

I can do this for the individual files, for example, if I write:

```
grep 'total moment' CeB6_new_lat_parm_4p119_scale_0p90/INFO.OUT | tail -n 1
```

This does exactly what I want, but there's lots of INFO.OUT files in lots of directories, how do I make a single command which will do this for all directories present?

Thank you

I suppose a way I could do this would be to grep:

```
grep 'total moment' CeB6_new_lat_parm_4p119_scale_*/INFO.OUT | tail -n 1
```

But then I won't know which directory this is from and it will also only give me the last line of the last file.

Thank you

Comment: example input and expected output would be nice to see, please update question.

Answer (score 1):

The more simple solution is make a script, you can use your favorite scripting language. For example in bash this is one solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE in $*/CeB6_new_lat_parm_4p119_scale_*/INFO.OUT
do
    echo -ne $FILE\\n\\t"->"
    tac $FILE | grep -m1 'total moment'
done
exit 0
```

[explanation script]
`for FILE in $*/CeB6_new_lat_parm_4p119_scale_*/INFO.OUT`  the loop for assigns each file to the variable FILE.
`echo -ne $FILE\\n\\t"->"`make more friendly the output of the script.
`tac $FILE` allows you to see a file line-by-line backwards.
`grep -m1 'total moment'` stop grep with the first match.
`tac $FILE | grep -m1 'total moment'` is slightly more efficient than using grep with the full text, but you can use `grep 'total moment' $FILE | tail -n 1` too 
[how use (suggestion)]
make the script /usr/local/bin/totalm.sh 
`chmod +x /usr/local/bin/totalm.sh`
`tolalm.sh /DIR_OF_FOLDERS`
if you prefer not use /DIR_OF_FOLDERS, you can change $* in the script for /DIR_OF_FOLDERS.